# Immediate vs load-on-first-access availability

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

The [docs say](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/tutorial.html#adding-and-updating-objects) (at the end of the linked section):

> After the Session inserts new rows in the database, all newly generated identifiers and database-generated defaults become available on the instance, either immediately or via load-on-first-access.

What's the difference between `immediately` and `load-on-first-access`? Doesn't SQLAlchemy know the new identifiers and defaults after it completed the `INSERT` operation, and so don't they become available even without reloading?

Comment: I think it refers more to "database-generated defaults" than "newly generated identifiers".

Comment: @univerio Got it, I edited my question to make it clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLAlchemy uses `INSERT .. RETURNING` for DBs that support it to fetch primary keys, or special functions like [`mysql_insert_id`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-insert-id.html) for DBs that don't.

For default values, it tries to use `RETURNING` but if it's not supported, it has to use another `SELECT`.

Furthermore, it may not be possible to use `RETURNING` (even on supported DBs) in specific situations (e.g. when the `INSERT` statements are batched, see [this mailing list post](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/sqlalchemy/3l6RhfAFpvM/3OqL6aXJo70J)).

Finally, SQLAlchemy only fetches the primary key by default after an `INSERT`. Thus, only the primary key is available "immediately" while unconfigured default columns are "load-on-first-access". If you need it to fetch generated values, specify [`server_default=FetchedValue()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/defaults.html#triggered-columns). (In the case where the DB does not support `RETURNING` and you specify `FetchedValue` for a column, I am not certain whether it still fetches the value with an immediate `SELECT` or simply falls back to "load-on-first-access".)

Answer (score 1):

**immediately:** SQLAlchemy gets a primary key from the database for each session object inserted and assigns it to the session object. The session object needs the primary key immediately since, prior to the transaction snapshot being committed, the object enters the persistent state and is added to the Identity Map collection which keys it on its primary key. [[The SQLAlchemy Session - In Depth]](http://pyvideo.org/pycon-us-2013/the-sqlalchemy-session-in-depth-0.html)

**load-on-first-access:** database-generated defaults associated with an object may never be used in its session. So to conserve resources these are [lazy loaded](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/lazyLoad.html) as needed.

Comment: `may never be used` because in order to use them, one needs to store and then retrieve the object, which is impossible in one season?